# The meaning of $\omega$ = df?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm reading Algebraic Topology by William Fulton and I am a little lost about 1-forms, which I assume to be the number of differentials according to the number of dimensions (correct me if I'm wrong. Since a 1-form is $\omega = A \, dx + B \, dy$, for

$$\omega = df$$

would that mean that the derivative of $f$ is in the 1-form?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A $1$-form is just a map that assigns to each point in your manifold a linear functional on the tangent space at that point, denoted $T_pM$. That is, for $p\in M$ we have that $\omega(p):=\omega_p\in T_p^\ast M$.

For simplicity, if you'd like just replace $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $T^\ast_pM=T_pM=\mathbb{R}^n$ and so a $1$-form just eats $n$-tuples and spits out an element of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$

Assuming  $ \ f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth, for some open $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\omega=df$ is just a specific one form. It's the one defined by, for $p\in U$, we have $(df)_p\in (\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$
where $(df)_p:T_pU=\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by sending $V\mapsto V\cdot \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_p$ the dot product of the vector $n$-tuple $V$ and the $n$-tuple $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_p$, otherwise known as the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction $V$.

Comment: wow, thanks for the help. I liked how you also put it simple terms. I wonder though, is it possible to call a 1-form a mapping from 1 dimension to an n-dimension?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not too sure I understand what you mean. The domain of a $1$-form (or $m$-form) is a manifold, which is locally the same thing as an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Actually, formally a $1$-form is a map from the manifold to the cotangent bundle, which is a manifold locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: did you mean 'function' instead of 'functional? Also, does $\omega(p):=\omega_p\in T_p^\ast M$ mean that you're assigning the 1-form the point that belongs to the cotangent bundle? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I meant functional! A functional on a vector space $V$ is just a linear function $V\to\mathbb{R}$. So here the vector space is $T_pM$ and the linear functional is $\omega_p$. The set $T_p^\ast M$ is the set of functionals on $T_pM$, and $\omega_p$ is just one such element.

And yes, the $1$-form $\omega$ is taking in the point $p$ and out putting the point in the cotangent bundle $\omega_p$.

Answer (score 0):

A smooth map $f: M \to N$ of manifolds (you can also think real space as an example) induces a map on tangent bundles. This is the generalization of the idea from multivariable calculus that total derivative at a point is a linear map. In particular, a smooth map $M \to \mathbb{R}$ defines a linear map from each tangent space to $\mathbb{R}$, that is, a 1-form. Explicitly, in local coordinates, we can write this as

$$ df = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i$$

Comment: what do you think is wrong with it? I percieved the question as having two possible concerns: (a) why is the derivative of a function a one form and/or (b) how do we realize this in the local description $\sum A_i dx_i$.